# Avoid text cutting in embed SVG

Tags: svg

I have a SVG with curved text, to be able to open it Illustartor or CorelDraw i wrote a PHP script that transforms text into latters(AI curved text bug). But after this transformation the piece of text is cut.

I've tried:

- Remove `viewbox` -> text object scaled
  [image]
- Change `text-anchor="start"` to `text-anchor="middle"` -> in this way the start and the end of the text is cut
  [image]
- Play with `preserveAspectRatio` -> doesn't give desired result

Also i dont think that increasing viewbox width will work becouse it still brings some transformation and can scale text that doesn't need it.

Also i have feeling that my current result isn't displayed propperly and it should be wider

Original:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="204.21875" 
    height="47.0625" viewBox="0 0 204.21875 47.0625"><g 
    id="0.11324252430130399"><text fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke- 
    width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text- 
    anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint- 
    order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data- 
    textspacing="0"><textPath xlink:href="#textPath-item-0"><tspan dy="0">some 
    random text</tspan></textPath></text></g><defs><path id="textPath-item-0" 
    d="M 8.671875 42.27672695769752 A 224.50591156146544 224.50591156146544 0 
    0 1 194.87404392183777 42.27672695769752"/></defs></svg></svg>
```

After Transformation

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="10in" height="19in" viewBox="0 0 291 389"><g xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><default:svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 204.21875 47.0625" x="41.794002" y="124.031094" width="199.315212" height="43.00006"><default:g id="0.11324252430130399"><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 10.508575634073 41.449625072391) rotate(-22.759904875656 0 0)">s</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 22.470359428287 36.535076221313) rotate(-19.364780943929 0 0)">o</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 36.342968127298 31.808497796986) rotate(-14.963694365763 0 0)">m</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 55.544337554077 26.873580391866) rotate(-10.562607787597 0 0)">e</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 68.514289571198 24.539662965228) rotate(-7.6704651790886 0 0)"> </default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 77.308993497502 23.399375413111) rotate(-5.4070492246034 0 0)">r</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 86.756329148838 22.565275109953) rotate(-2.5149066160946 0 0)">a</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 100.5411746455 22.065879210017) rotate(1.0059626464378 0 0)">n</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 114.33067013955 22.413982141576) rotate(4.5268319089703 0 0)">d</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 128.07276017669 23.608269813315) rotate(8.0477011715028 0 0)">o</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 142.56376901114 25.799269283198) rotate(12.448787749668 0 0)">m</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 161.28748096036 30.094565435109) rotate(16.22114767381 0 0)"> </default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 169.7904205993 32.613908672806) rotate(18.484563628295 0 0)">t</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 178.76606186368 35.677523876761) rotate(21.376706236804 0 0)">e</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 191.57198798021 40.803888858848) rotate(24.897575499337 0 0)">x</default:text><default:text xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#FF0000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="" y="" text-anchor="start" font-size="24px" font-family="arial" style="paint-order:stroke;" data-textcurve="49" data-itemzoom="1 1" data-textspacing="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 203.49025065141 46.427218902602) rotate(27.789718107846 0 0)">t</default:text></default:g><default:defs><default:path id="textPath-item-0" d="M 8.671875 42.27672695769752 A 224.50591156146544 224.50591156146544 0 0 1 194.87404392183777 42.27672695769752"></default:path></default:defs></default:svg></g></svg>
```

Here you can see that i do keep original viewport and width/height

What is the propper way to draw this object so it isn't cut and it isn't scaled?

Answer (score 0):

The problems here are not about `svg`, but about the transformation in the PHP script. You can see why in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/mohingudino/pen/oKaqRj). I put your original svg code in red plus some letters of the transformation in blue. As you can see, the letters are not in the same coordinates, and that is why the result is cropped by the viewport. Also, a couple of points about the transformed svg code:

- Several `<text>` tags appear as `<default:text>`.This looks like a problem from the PHP script.
- The `id` of the `<g>` element is `"0.11324252430130399"`. Perhaps this number should be somewhere else?
- Like in the original code, there is an `<svg>` inside another `<svg>`. This may cause problems somewhere. Consider removing the outher svg.

In summary, you should revise the PHP transformation, the svg code is behaving correctly.